# How to get the latest version ID for an Amazon S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Given a valid Amazon S3 path that specifies which bucket, which file to get version ID, how can I get the latest version ID using AWS SDK JAVA API?

I tried to search API in https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/, but did not find API that returns a VersionID.

The function signature is `String getLatestVersionID(String S3Path);`

Thx

Comment: `headObject` is what you are looking for

Comment: The accepted answer didn't help me, but basically, a HEAD request to the S3 object url will return the version id in the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the version Id value by invoking the [GetObjectRequest objects versionId](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html#versionId--) method. Here is the code for this:

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetObjectData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GetObjectData <bucketName> <keyName> <path>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket name. \n\n"+
                "    keyName - the key name. \n\n"+
                "    path - the path where the file is written to. \n\n";

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        String path = args[2];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getObjectBytes(s3,bucketName,keyName, path);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.main]
    public static void getObjectBytes (S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName, String path ) {

        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .key(keyName)
                    .versionId("<Set Version ID>")
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

            // Write the data to a local file
            File myFile = new File(path );
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            os.write(data);
            System.out.println("Successfully obtained bytes from an S3 object");
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
           System.exit(1);
        }
        // snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.main]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need to set version id.   I want to get the latest version Id.